# Visual Studio, TFS, MVC and Classic ASP Project Setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs, asp-classic

There are a number of questions existing but I am just trying to clarify best practice on this. I have Classic ASP site that we wish to migrate to MVC3. I am trying to decide the best project structure for setting this all up in a new Visual Studio 2010, TFS environment.

I want to start a new Solution in Visual Studio and get the structure correct. I want it done right as I have about 30 projects to migrate.

In most projects I have a few hundred ASP, HTML, JavaScript, CSS files etc. and an Access Database.

I saw it mentioned best practice was to keep the ASP files in a seperate project.
So what should I setup? There is no Classic ASP project template. So I guess I need to create some sort of project to put my ASP files. Should I setup an empty MVC application and add the ASP to that?  Where do I keep the existing JS/images etc. Should these also existing with the Classic ASP. What should the default project be?

What about Source Control (I assume I just add everything like I would in a normal app). What about publishing etc. I guess I just need IIS web server with Classic ASP support turned on. Can I enable it at the application level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an "Empty web application" project, add your files/folders in the same structure as they existed on the web server. Map a virtual directory from IIS to your project folder and you're good to go. Develop your replacement MVC version in a separate project, rather than trying to convert the classic project in a piecemeal fashion.

Also, note that [debugging support for classic ASP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241740.aspx) is still available in VS2010.

Edit: If you want to [share state between classic ASP and ASP.net, Microsoft have an article on the topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx).

Comment: Would that be an ASP.Net Web Application Project? Yeah luckily knew about the debugging. My main concern next will be try to share the login session between the MVC App and ASP!

Comment: That's the one yes. Also added a link to my answer regarding sharing session state.